# VSCode doesnt pull the index.js when I load the index.html

Tags: javascript, html, windows, visual-studio-code, src

I'm having an issue where when I open my index.html in the browser, it isnt loading my index.js.

If I use the developer tools, and look into sources, I find my index.js file has not loaded correctly. Has anyone else run into this issue?

I was having no problems past few weeks but must have entered something into my terminal that caused my files to longer travel together.

Please let me know if there's any additional info I can share.
This problem is persisting through different directories so its a major issue. None of my documents are sending the index.js data with the index.html!

Thanks for your help,
Freaking out coder

Comment: is it possible to show the code? Is it linked properly in the src element? Can you try using inline JS to see if that works?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the editor has nothing to do with file loading in the browser.

Second, you probably have a typo in the file path and that's all. Maybe you moved a file and didn't update the path?

Comment: This doesnt look like a definitve anwer to me. I think if you need more info from OP to give a good answer, you should use the comments.

Comment: This is true, but I multiple times see people googling the problem, getting on the stack overflow and omitting the comments at all while reading. Just wanted to make it easier for someone who will ever find this question.